# AlarmManager not triggering onReceived

Tags: java, android, timer, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have created a class called "VIAlarmManager" and in there I create an AlarmManager and set some properties. But no matter what, the Alarm is not fired, am I doing something wrong ? I try to call an task that is repeated in an given interval (eg 1 Minuten / 2 Minutes / 15 Minutes) and it should also be executed while in sleep.

Here is my code:

```
public final class VIAlarmManager{

public static AlarmManager alarmManager;
public int freq = 60;

public VIAlarmManager(int freq_in_sec){
    this.freq = freq_in_sec;
}

public void setFrequency(int freq_in_sec){
    this.freq = freq_in_sec;
}

public void setAlarm(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.Context, VIAlarmManager.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.Context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60 * 1, pendingIntent);
}

public void cancleAlarm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.Context, VIAlarm_Heartbeat.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.Context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}




public static class VIAlarm_Heartbeat extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.w("AlarmManager", "Calling Heartbeat now");
        MainActivity.beat.beat();
    }
}}
```

My AndroidManifest contains this line:

```
<receiver android:name="com.videro.util.VIAlarmManager$VIAlarm_Heartbeat" android:enabled="true" ></receiver>
```

And in my main activity I call:

```
 AlarmManager = new VIAlarmManager(60);
 AlarmManager.setAlarm();
```

Comment: Why you saying **MainActivity.Context** for line `alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);`. instead of that make a constructor and pass context to it and use that context as `context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);`

Comment: It's a static reference to the application Context. But that shouldn't be a problem , right ?

Answer (score 0):

If its a simple Alarm you require, the classical way is to use an **Activity** with `TimePicker` to select the time  and a **BroadcastReceiver** to kick the Alarm along with a **Service** to send Notification to the user.

[Here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial/) is a working way on how you can do it! Hope it helps:)

Comment: Well, basically I need to call a function every 1 / 2 / 15 Minutes, and that function has to be called even if the device is in deepsleep